# Software to determine the field names of PDF forms

Tags: pdf

I currently have a PDF form that I can fill out.  I can upload the PDF to a piece of software that I purchased that converts form values to CSV.  The problem is that the CSV shows headers like `Field1, Field2, Group1, Group2, etc...` instead of human readable labels like `FirstName, LastName, Gender, PreferredMethodOfContact etc...` .

Right now, I have to do a bunch of experiments to guess whether `Field1` means `FirstName` and whether `Field2` means `LastName`, and whether `Group1` means `Gender` etc...

Is there a software that I can use to inspect a PDF form and see which field labels maps to which actual form fields? It can run on Mac or Windows. It can be paid software as long as it doesn't cost more then $10k USD / year

Comment: are you sure the fields really have those human readable labels?

Comment: can you share the PDF that you are working with?

Comment: The fields do not need to be human readable because I can write a JavaScript plugin to map group1 to preferred method of contact, group2 to gender, group3 to family income, field2 to are you a Canadian citizen  etc...the problem is the only way I know that group1 is preferred method of contact is through a lot of trial and error and experimentation.  I need to write a bunch fake data into the form, and then identify remember that value `1` means female for field23 ...oh wait...maybe field23 was corporation status...I can't remember

Comment: It would be nice if I can house mouse over a pdf field, and then a tooltip shows up and tells me what the field label is....so if I hover over the form field for Did you have surgery within past 5 years, a popup says that is Radio1089.  Then I can write into my JavaScript plugin `radio1089=surgery5years`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [QuickPDF Library](https://www.debenu.com/blog/debenu-quick-pdf-library-11-15-released.html) from [Foxit](https://www.foxit.com/).

Comment: Can you explain why? How to use...

Comment: `It can be paid software as long as it doesn't cost more then $10k USD / year` It cost less than 500USD. It works. What is your prefered language ?

Comment: [FormFieldCount](https://www.debenu.com/docs/pdf_library_reference/FormFieldCount.php) + [GetFormFieldTitle](https://www.debenu.com/docs/pdf_library_reference/GetFormFieldTitle.php) .... take a look at: [Example 1](http://www.quickpdf.org/forum/setformfieldvalue-doesnt-work-when-field-type-is-p_topic3840.html) [Example 2](http://www.quickpdf.org/forum/field-property-font-size-alignment-arent-preserve_topic3844.html) [Tutorials](https://www.debenu.com/products/development/debenu-pdf-library/help/tutorials/)

Comment: `It would be nice if I can house mouse over a pdf field, and then a tooltip shows up and tells me what the field label is.` @John take a look for [SetFormFieldCaption](https://www.debenu.com/docs/pdf_library_reference/SetFormFieldCaption.php) and [SetFormFieldDescription](https://www.debenu.com/docs/pdf_library_reference/SetFormFieldDescription.php) I think one of them will be those you want to use.